# Will Oracle Trigger cause performance issues

Tags: triggers, oracle11g

I have around 100+ tables in my application. Most of the update queries do not update the last updated time column. There are 100s of queries so I am a bit skeptical modifying all the queries to include last updated time. The alternate option that I was looking at was to create a an oracle trigger for all the tables and get the lastupdatedtime field updated using a trigger when the relevant row gets updated.

Most of my tables have more than a million rows. Will Oracle trigger cause any performance issues? Below is the high level syntax that I am thinking of :

```
  create  OR REPLACE  trigger  TRIG_UPDATE
    before update  on TESTSAMPLE
    for each row
    declare
    begin

      if (updating) then
        :new.last_update :=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
     end if;
  end;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any general performance question, the only realistic answer is to try it in your environment and benchmark the actual performance impact you see.  Adding triggers will create significant performance issues in some environments and will have no measurable impact on others.  We can't know with certainty which category your system will fall into (or whether it will fall into some intermediate regime).

Adding a trigger is going to force two SQL to PL/SQL context shifts for every row that you update.  For an average OLTP system where you're modifying relatively few rows, that overhead is likely to be relatively low.  For an average data warehouse system where you're updating millions of rows at a time, on the other hand, that overhead is likely to be quite significant.  For an average OLTP system where you're not worried about a few milliseconds here or there, a trigger probably isn't going to be significant.  If, on the other hand, you're focusing heavily on scaling out or you've got extremely tight service level agreements, adding triggers may create an issue.

From a functionality standpoint, you should also be aware that an `UPDATE` statement that modifies multiple rows will generally end up with different `last_update` values if you use a trigger rather than the same `last_update` value if you add the `last_update` modification to the `UPDATE` statement.  That may or may not be relevant to you but it is something to be aware of.

Just as a side note, there doesn't appear to be any reason to have an `if (updating)` statement in your code.  If you're writing a `before update` trigger, you're always going to be doing an update so it doesn't really make sense to check whether you're doing an update.

Comment: Sorry , had one more question. Will the trigger lock the table and cause any additional inserts or updates to wait?

Comment: @PunterVicky - That depends on exactly what you're asking.  The presence or absence of a trigger doesn't change what locks are taken out.  It will, presumably, cause the locks that the `UPDATE` statement takes out (on the table and on the individual rows) to be held longer (how much longer, though, is an open question).  That could cause other sessions to wait more though for a normal OLTP application, you'd really only be concerned about the row-level locks in that case not the table locks which are only doing things like protecting the table from DDL.